# Removing everything but html tags from a corpus

Tags: regex, r, text-mining, tm

I'm using the package `tm`. I have a corpus full of html document and I would like to remove everything but the html tags. I've been trying to do that for a few days but I don't seem to be able to find any good solution.

For example, let's say I have a document like this :

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>hello</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

I would want the document to become like this:

```
<html> <body> <h1>
```

(Or with the closing tags, I don't really mind.)

My goal is to count how many times each tag is used in a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with tm, but here's how you could do it using Regular Expressions.

(Presupposition: your string starts and ends with an HTML tag)

```
str <- "<html><body><p>test<p>test2</body></html>"
str <- gsub(">[^<^>]+<", "> <", str) # remove all the text in between HTML tags, leaving only HTML tags (opening and closing)
str <- gsub("</[^<^>]+>", "", str) #remove all closing HTML tags.
```

That would leave you with your desired string.

If you're new to RegEx, check out [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for additional info getting started. Basically, the first gsub above is going to replace all text in between `>` and `<` which isn't an open or close bracket (i.e. all non-tag text). The second gsub will replace all text which starts with `</` and ends with `>` with nothing -- removing the closing tags from the string

Comment: This might work if he has really simple html but in general you cant parse html with a regular expression. For instance, this won't string out attributes.

Comment: @frankc If you're going to leave that comment, you really ought to link to [The Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/324364). :)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into something like http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/XML/html/xmlTreeParse.html

In the link above, look at the example code.  There is a section that shows how to print the entities. I haven't used this package so I can't vouch for it directly.

Answer (score 0):

**(1) gsubfn**

Assuming `s` is the input string (it may contain newlines) this matches `<` followed by anything that is not `/`, `>` or a space and extracts it into tags.  The `table` function tabulates the occurrences:

```
library(gsubfn)
tags <- strapply(tolower(s), "\\<([^/> ]+)", c, simplify = unlist)
table(tags)
```

For example,

```
s <- "<html>
<body>

<h1>hello</h1>

</body>
</html>"
tags <- strapply(tolower(s), "\\<([^/> ]+)", c, simplify = unlist)
table(tags)
```

gives this:

```
tags
body   h1 html 
   1    1    1
```

If your file is very large then [the development version of gsubfn](http://gsubfn.google.code) has a fast version called `strapplyc` .

**(2) XML**

The above approach could get confused if there are `<` and `>` symbols in quoted strings and other border cases.  There may not be any such instances in your input anyways but just in case this second approach should not have that problem:

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlTreeParse(tolower(s), asText = TRUE, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
tags <- xpathSApply(doc, "//*", xmlName)
table(tags)
```